# How to use ngFor with complex json in angular to render ul li data

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a simple html view with some ul and li. But I need to get the same structure with ngfor using the array 'jsonarray' in the code.Here is the code below https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eigvsq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

### app.component.html

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <h5>Red</h5>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <h5>Blue</h5>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";
  jsonarray = {
    id: "0001",
    Red: [
      { id: "1001", Order: 1 },
      { id: "1002", Order: 2 },
      { id: "1003", Order: 3 }
    ],
    Blue: [
      { id: "5001", Order: 4 },
      { id: "5002", Order: 5 },
      { id: "5005", Order: 6 }
    ]
  };

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Comment: If you know you need a `ngFor`, then why aren't you writing it using an `ngFor`? Or, did you want someone to write this for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need leave only the values you want to show in the template, I mean remove the `id: '0001'` field from your *jsonarray* property. Then, in the template you can use [*keyvalue* pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe):

```
  <ul>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of jsonarray | keyvalue">
      <h5>{{item.key}}</h5>
      <li *ngFor="let subItem of item.value">
        {{subItem.Order}}
      </li>
    </ng-container>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let data of jsonarray|keyvalue: originalOrder">
            <ng-container *ngIf="data.key !== id">
                <h5>{{data.key}}</h5>
                <ng-container *ngFor="let fields of data.value">
                    <li>{{fields.Order}}</li>
                </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Working Stackblitz :-

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ge4vjn?file=src/app/app.component.html